# Error:Cannot create directory \app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\zip-cache

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Suddenly Error display after build working project.

How to sole this error?

> Error:Cannot create directory
>   \app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\zip-cache

**I tried Below solutions.**

1. Delete .gradle from the user/username/.gradle and start Android Studio

   - Not working
2. Invalidate Caches and Restart

   - Not Working
3. Clean Project and Build Project

   - Not Working

Answer (score 10):

i have same problem before, it caused by i don't have the write permission for app/build folder(i have no idea why).

So i give the permission to the folder like below

`sudo chmod -R a=rwx app`

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem before, it caused by i don't have the write permission for app folder.Go to android folder 
For Mac 
`sudo chmod -R a=rwx app`
and then

```
./gradlew
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions problem. Running Android Studio as Administrator worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

> chmod -R 777 android

then

> chmod -R 777 android/app

Comment: Please provide information on why this should work or why he should try it. (Explain your answer)