# How to solve this error app:packageDebug FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception, filenotfounderror

> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatter\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Give permission to the folder using  
sudo chmod -R a=rwx app   Check these solutions. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855827/errorcannot-create-directory-app-build-intermediates-incremental-packagedebug

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that your anti-virus is preventing the access to the files. Make the Android Studio application as trusted application(recommended) or try turning off your antivirus.

Comment: How to Make Android Studio Trusted? Can you please tell me

Comment: You find that option settings in your antivirus' application.